Technical Analysis Questions Should not be Allowed on this Site
A statement, not a question.  As I understand it this site is for practitioners and students of quant finance, and technical analysis might be regarded as the antithesis of quant finance.  We view prices as random processes in almost every modern model I can think of, and hence trying to discern patterns is moot and off-topic to us.   Whether or not this is the right viewpoint is very debatable, but technical analysis is a far cry from modern quant finance and hence takes up space for more relevant questions.  
Here's an example: How to fully replicate ADX + DI Indicators in Excel?
I haven't seen other discussions on this, so I'd be happy to hear everyone's opinion.

Related: http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/q/81/848

As a practitioner I view Technical analysis as within the scope of discussion as most TA models are very crude filters on a price/return time series that may have some use.
Secondly, the ability to test hypotheses whether they be "technical analysis", "quantitative", is extremely important so guiding users into systematic implementations of TA ideas would be very helpful.
Your assumptions about price being random is silly, and for those of us whose bank accounts depend on the performance of their models would be a dangerous assumption IMO.
